# iDisk-like features on Lion Server

Tags: ftp, webdav, dropbox, osx-server

The imminent death of iDisk is a bummer. I have used it for years to easily share files with clients without asking them to boot up their FTP software.

I am curious to know if there is a way to mimic iDisk's file sharing features through Lion Server. Specifically, the ability to share links to specific files and have them downloaded through a web browser. I miss the clean interface of iDisk through MobileMe.

I realize that there are third party providers like Dropbox and YouSendIt, but it would be nice to serve the files directly from our local server. I originally thought WebDav might be the answer, but it seems that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install additional software to get that functionality. I've used and had good luck with Boxroom (http://boxroom.rubyforge.org/) but it requires Rails which may be too much work to install if you don't need it for anything else.

Searching for "open source php file manager" turns up a range of options which should work well on Lion as it has PHP already installed. I have also seen Java alternatives, some of which run on top of WebDAV, so it is probably best to start with the development language you are most comfortable with deploying and work from there.

Sorry I couldn't be more specific, my Mini is in transit so I haven't had direct experience with Lion server yet:)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Storage Made Easy Mac client. It works a similar way to the original iDisk but also had sync capability. See: https://storagemadeeasy.com/MacCloudTools/ and https://storagemadeeasy.com/wiki/maccloudtools/. There is a native disk piece and also a sync like dropbox piece to the App.